# Correct tensor sizes for a pixel based classification of multidimensional satellite imagery with neural network

Tags: neural-networks, python

I've successfully worked through a few samples that take an entire image and apply one class to it.  I want to classify each pixel in an image.  I keep getting hung up when attempting to calculate loss.

I have a single 10 band satellite image tiled into 128x128 images.  The last band is the classification so 9, 128, 128 are inputs and 1, 128, 128 are labels.

I'm using a batch of 16 and 8 classes that fall between 0 and 255.

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.5)
```

Simple test model

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Linear(147456, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 8) #Not sure 8 is correct

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 147456)
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        return self.fc2(x)
```

Here is the loop in my train method

```
for idx, data in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader, desc="training")):
    inputs = Variable(data['sat_img'].cuda())
    labels = Variable(data['map_img'].cuda())

    # zero the parameter gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # forward
    outputs = model(inputs)
    print('inputs', inputs.shape)
    print('labels', labels.shape)
    print('outputs', outputs.shape)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels.long().view(-1)) #CRASH HERE
```

The loop above crashes when I call loss.  The print out of shapes is:

```
inputs: torch.Size([16, 9, 128, 128])
labels: torch.Size([16, 128, 128])
outputs: torch.Size([16, 8])
```

Error:

```
Expected input batch_size (16) to match target batch_size (262144).
```

Question:
CrossEntropyLoss expects a tensor of size C which are the weights for each of my 8 classes.  Currently the shape of that is 16 batches, 8 classes.  It also expects a batch size of correct answers.  But I have 128x128 answers and I can't use a 2D array.  Should I use a different criterion?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to CV! It is a bit unclear whether the question is about the usage of the code (which would be misplaced at CV) or the underlying principle. Could you please ask the question more specific to the point?

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't aware CV wasn't for code.  I assumed all stackexchange sites were.  I changed my question to hopefully fit better.

Comment: I changed my model to conv2d instead of linear and things went much better.